# How to disable Mat-tree component based on a condition?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I am using **Angular Material 6**. I am unable to disable my mat-tree component:

```
<mat-tree>
    <!-- // -->
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: use `<app-mat-tree></app-mat-tree *ngIf="condition">`

Comment: Hello @Morl could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Where is your code? And what have you tried?

Comment: Hi I would like to keep the mat tree in UI. What I meant by disabling means I want to gray out the whole mat tree.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I tried to add disable attribute according the documentation but it doesn't works as expected. It will works if you simply disabled elements inside tree nodes

```
<mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
                    [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
              ----> [disabled]="isDisabled" <----
                    (change)="leafNodeSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
```

Complete code:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding [disabled]="isDisabled">
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
                    [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
                    [disabled]="isDisabled"
                    (change)="leafNodeSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-tree-node>

    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding [disabled]="isDisabled">
      <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [disabled]="isDisabled">
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-checkbox [checked]="isDescendantsAllSelected(node)"
                    [disabled]="isDisabled"
                    [indeterminate]="isDescendantPartiallySelected(node)"
                    (change)="nodeSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
    </mat-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

Comment: the same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

```
<any-component *ngIf='your_condition' ... > </any-component>
```

would work. For Instance,

```
 <any-component *ngIf='isShown == true' ... > </any-component>
```

**Edit:  I need to show it on UI. I need to gray out the whole tree**

you can use `@disabled` attribute

```
<mat-tree>
  <mat-tree-node [disabled]='isDisabled'> parent node </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node [disabled]='isDisabled'> -- child node1 </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node [disabled]='isDisabled'> -- child node2 </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: I need to show it on UI. I need to gray out the whole tree.

Comment: try with [disabled]="true" first

Comment: I did. For Mat-tree node asa well as Mat-nested tree node, still not working!

Comment: According to [the official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api#directives) it needs to work